# Selecting a function overload based on runtime data?

Tags: c++

I have created a finite state machine using the boost msm library. The events and their transitions are defined declaratively at compile-time. At runtime however, there needs to be some code that selects the right event based the input data. Currently the code looks like this:

```
enum : unsigned {
    fin = (1 << 0),
    syn = (1 << 1),
    ack = (1 << 4)
    // etc...
};

// events
struct receive_syn {};
struct receive_syn_ack {};
struct receive_fin {};
struct receive_fin_ack {};
struct receive_ack {};
// etc..

void receive(const Segment& segment)
{
    switch (segment.getFlags())
    {
        case syn|ack: state_machine.process_event(receive_syn_ack{}); break;
        case syn:     state_machine.process_event(receive_syn{}); break;
        case fin|ack: state_machine.process_event(receive_fin_ack{}); break;
        case fin:     state_machine.process_event(receive_fin{}); break;
        case ack:     state_machine.process_event(receive_ack{}); break;
        // etc..
    }
}
```

It works and it's probably fast. However, I feel that this should be written in a more declarative style.

How can I implement this in a higher-level style of programming without introducing additional runtime overhead?

For reference, here is a [boost::msm example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/msm/doc/HTML/examples/SimpleWithFunctors2.cpp).

Comment: I'd recommend a hash table of function pointers, that's the first thing I usually do in this situation. Hash table has O(1) lookup speed so it would perform even better than your current implementation.

Comment: The compiler might translate the switch into a lookup table; in that case the performance of the current implementation won't be worse than a hash table.

Comment: I suspect calculation of a hash value plus invocation of function pointer will be more expensive than the switch. Also `O(1)` is not necessarily faster than `O(n)`. Big-O is characterizes the growth rate. In my case N is relatively small (<20).

Comment: If you make the values of the enum a continuous series of integers then the enum can be used as the index into a table.

Comment: Are `receive_syn_ack` etc. empty types?

Comment: @celtschk Yes. They are used for overload selection. (See my edit.)

Comment: In that case, I'd simplify it with a single templated type `template<unsigned> struct receive {};`. This doesn't solve your question, but it simplifies your code by removing a bunch of definitions.

Comment: Another question: All the members of your enum are of the form `1<<n`, right?

Comment: @celtschk Yes. That is the case.

Comment: I feel like I’m missing something here, and I’ve never used this particular Boost library. But shouldn’t *the whole point* of a state machine library be to avoid having to code this manually, rather than *declaring* transitions somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

Warning! Not tested.

You could use a compile-time map to connect the flags to the type of objects to pass:

```
template < unsigned tflags, typename ttype >
struct kv
{
    static const unsigned flags = tflags;
    using type = ttype;
};


using flag_type_map = std::tuple
    <
        kv<syn|ack, receive_syn_ack>,
        kv<syn    , receive_syn    >,
        kv<fin|ack, receive_fin_ack>,
        kv<fin    , receive_fin    >,
        kv<ack    , receive_ack    >
    >;
```

In order to process this at run-time, you'd have to do some kind of iteration or recursion. If the compiler is smart enough (and inlines), you could get the same performance.

```
template < typename >
struct tuple_pop;

  template < typename T, typename... TT >
  struct tuple_pop < std::tuple < T, TT... > >
  {
      using type = std::tuple < TT... >;
  };

template < typename T >
void call(unsigned flags, std::true_type)
{
    throw std::invalid_argument("flag combination not known / invalid");
}

template < typename T >
void call(unsigned flags, std::false_type = {})
{
    using tuple_first = typename std::tuple_element<0, T>::type;
    using tuple_popped = typename tuple_pop<T>::type;
    using is_last = std::integral_constant<bool,
                                           0 == -1+std::tuple_size<T>::value >;

    if(flags == tuple_first::flags)
    {
        // could replace this hard-wired call with a passed function object
        // to make it more generic
        state_machine.process_event( typename tuple_first::type{} );
    }else
    {
        create_obj<tuple_popped>(flags, is_last{});
    }
}

void receive(const Segment& segment)
{
    call<flag_type_map>(segment.getFlags());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the following should work (untested code), and with not too many flags should still be quite efficient — O(log n), but with fast iteration:

```
// your enum
enum: unsigned
{
  fin = (1 << 0),
  syn = (1 << 1),
  ack = (1 << 4)
  // etc...
};

// this is used for the magic:
unsigned all = fin|syn|ack|...;

// this replaces your individual receive types:
template<unsigned> struct receive {};

// this is the magic translation to compile time
template<unsigned bit = 1, unsigned mask = all, unsigned value = 0> struct call
{
  void process(state_machine_type& state_machine, unsigned flags)
  {
    if (flags & bit)
      call<(bit << 1), mask & ~bit, value | bit>::process(state_machine, flags);
    else
      call<(bit << 1), mask & ~bit, value>::process(state_machine, flags);
  }
};

template<unsigned bit, unsigned value> struct call<bit, 0, value>
{
  void process(state_machine_type& state_machine, unsigned)
  {
    state_machine.process_event(receive<value>{});
  }
};

// the rewrite of your receive function
void receive(const Segment& segment)
{
  call<>::process(state_machine, segment.getFlags());
}
```

Comment: You also deserve a +1. I wonder what the compilers will make of our attempts when using optimizations. (of course, yours has a better no-optimization runtime)

Comment: FYI: [optimized](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=40c547ea69512f290798eeb127e963d7-c09fe68be7e6cb6858740863f3d98ee0) vs [unoptimized](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=40c547ea69512f290798eeb127e963d7-ac9818afa4bb521fb9904defd4d3f414) generated assembly. There's a huge  difference.